# I lost my windows grub after dist upgrade

Tags: grub, microsoft-windows

everybody.

Recently I upgrade the OS using dist upgrade. Today I tried to start Windows and can't. I suspected to be some grub error, so I installed grub-customizer and confirmed that there's no Windows grub entry. Can I reinstall Windows grub only using Elementary OS? Someone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `sudo update-grub` and reboot help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are dual booting Windows and elementary. If that's the case, just install `boot-repair` with `sudo apt install boot-repair -y` and press Recommended Repair
[image: Recommended Repair]

It will fix everything automatically.

Comment: It works. Now I can boot Windows, but seems like I’m in another user account. Some softwares that were installed before weren’t right now. Do you know the reason?

Comment: That's weird...Did you try to reinstall windows? Did you resize your windows partition or let elementary resize automatically the partitions when you were installing it? I'm not sure what's the issue but it's impossible that boot-repair affected it since it only edits a hidden boot partition and not your system partition.

Comment: I found that's a windows problem. So, thank you for the help!